# Bedeutung von "aus dem Ei"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Was bedeutet "aus dem Ei" im folgenden Satz:

> Rückschlüsse *aus dem Ei*

Es handelt sich wahrscheinlich um einen Teil einer Redewendung, die kann ich jedoch nicht finden. Die einzige Redewendung, die ich gefunden habe, ist *wie aus dem Ei gepellt sein* , das passt aber nicht.

Comment: Ohne Verb ist das kein vollständiger Satz ;). Und ohne weiteren Kontext wird es schwer, diese Frage zu beantworten.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/wirtschaftspolitik/fipronil-eier-rueckschluesse-aus-dem-skandal-15145721.html? Bei dem Satz "Rückschlüsse aus dem EI" handelt es sich demnach um den Titel eines Kommentars zur Fipronil-Problematik.

Comment: Dann ist das nur eine Anspielung auf das Problem und lässt sich nicht in anderen Fällen verwenden?

Comment: Offen gesagt verstehe ich den Sinn der Überschrift selber nicht so richtig. Er ergibt sich m.E. auch nicht aus dem Inhalt des Kommentars. Seltsamerweise deutet die URL des Kommentars überdies auf einen anderen Titel hin: "Rückschlüsse aus dem Skandal". Vielleicht hat da nur jemand zu flott auf "Veröffentlichen" geklickt...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Phrase »aus dem Ei« ist sehr alt. Es ist eine wörtliche Übersetzung der lateinischen Phrase »ex ovo«, die man z.B. in diesem Zitat findet:

> Omne vivum ex ovo.
>   Alles Leben kommt aus dem Ei. (wörtlich: *Alles Leben aus Ei.*)
>   <sub>*(von Francesco Redi, 1626 - 1697, Arzt und Dichter)*</sub>

Man verwendet »aus dem Ei«, aber auch »ex ovo« manchmal, um darauf hinzuweisen, dass man etwas auf seinen grundlegendsten Ursprung hin zurückführt.

In dem als »Kommentar« klassifizierten Artikel mit dem Titel »[Rückschlüsse aus dem Ei](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/wirtschaftspolitik/fipronil-eier-rueckschluesse-aus-dem-skandal-15145721.html)«, der am 11.8.2017 in der FAZ erschienen ist, wird diese Phrase aber in einem doppeldeutigen Sinn verwendet: Es geht darin um einen Lebensmittelskandal, bei dem ein Insektizid (Fibronil) in Hühnerställen ausgebracht wurde, woraufhin es über das Futter in die Hühner und dann weiter in die Eier gelangt ist.

In dem Artikel werden mögliche Rückschlüsse behandelt, die man aus diesem Ei-Skandal ziehen kann.

Comment: Eine Antwort, wie aus dem Ei gepellt.